# Application Form Tennis Tournament

Tags: php, html

For an exercise I need to make a PHP form that allows people to apply for a tennis tournament. It needs to have a place to fill in your first name, last name, tennis club, your skill level (ranging 1-7), your desired category (also ranging 1-7), your email address and potential comments the applicant may have.

Structuring the form is not the problem and a first version is made. However, demands have changed and it is now required for us to make sure that the applicant's skill level can't be **lower** than the desired category they are playing in as these are linked directly to skill. It is allowed to play in a category higher than your level. To illustrate it more clearly I have a example below.

The limit for this demand, example 1:

- Person 1's skill level is 4
- Person 1's desired category is 5
- Person 1 **cannot** play in category 5

Example 2:

- Person 2's skill level is 4
- Person 2's desired category is 3
- Person 2 **can** play in category 3

Example 3:

- Person 3's skill level is 2
- Person 3's desired category is 2
- Person 3 **can** play in category 2

Like said before, the first version is already finished but I'm not really sure how to incorporate these new needs into the file. The code can be found below:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Application form</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    Welcome to this application form for our tennis tournament. In order to succesfully apply yourself for this tournament we want to know the following information about you as an athlete; your first name, your seconde name, your club, your licence number, category, email adresses and extra information if deemed of use by you. Good luck and we look forward to seeing you at the tournament.
  </form>
</h3>
<label for="textfield2">First name:</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2">
<label for="textfield3"><br>
  Last name:</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield3" id="textfield3">
<label for="textfield4"><br>
  Extra (optional):</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
<label for="textfield4"><br>
  Club:</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield4" id="textfield4">
<h1>Your license number, this is needed to ensure that your results are valid.</h1>
<table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_3">
      License number 1</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="2" id="RadioGroup1_4">
      License number 2</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="3" id="RadioGroup1_5">
      License number 3</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="4 " id="RadioGroup1_6">
      License number 4</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="5" id="RadioGroup1_7">
      License number 5</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="6" id="RadioGroup1_8">
      License number 6<br>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="7" id="RadioGroup1_9">
      License number 7</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h1>Your category, arranged by skill.</h1>
<table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="7" id="Categorie_0">
Not skilled - 7<br>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="6" id="Categorie_1">
Less skilled - 6</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="5" id="Categorie_2">
Unskilled - 5</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="4" id="Categorie_3">
      Average - 4</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="3" id="Categorie_4">
Skilled - 3</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="2" id="Categorie_5">
Good - 2</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="1" id="Categorie_6">
Genius - 1</label>
      <label for="email"><br>
    Your email adress:</label>      <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label for="textarea">Comments and extra information:</label>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
<table width="200">
  <tr> </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions regarding above information feel free to ask. All tips are welcome regarding both the question above and the coding in general.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best to start with the manual on forms/PHP http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is that you can make a table in your database of skills vs category... or save an array in your javascript (if this kind of Category.num and Category.requiredSkillLevel pairs are less in number and are fixed) for client side validation... Now if the user enters his skill level and his desired category, You can easily test

```
if(UserInput.category == Category.num){
  if(UserInput.skills < Category.requiredSkillLevel){
     alert("Participant is not eligible to participate in this category.");
}
else{
alert("Participant is eligible");
}
```

```js
function validateForm(){
  
  var skill = $("input[type='radio'][name='RadioGroup1']:checked").val();
  var cat = $("input[type='radio'][name='Categorie']:checked").val();
  if(skill<cat){
    alert("Not Eligible");
      return false;
    }
  else{
    alert("Eligible!");
    return true;
  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
    Welcome to this application form for our tennis tournament. In order to succesfully apply yourself for this tournament we want to know the following information about you as an athlete; your first name, your seconde name, your club, your licence number, category, email adresses and extra information if deemed of use by you. Good luck and we look forward to seeing you at the tournament.
</h3>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  
<label for="textfield2">First name:</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2">
<label for="textfield3"><br>
  Last name:</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield3" id="textfield3">
<label for="textfield4"><br>
  Extra (optional):</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
<label for="textfield4"><br>
  Club:</label>
<input type="text" name="textfield4" id="textfield4">
<h1>Your license number, this is needed to ensure that your results are valid.</h1>
<table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_3">
      License number 1</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="2" id="RadioGroup1_4">
      License number 2</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="3" id="RadioGroup1_5">
      License number 3</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="4 " id="RadioGroup1_6">
      License number 4</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="5" id="RadioGroup1_7">
      License number 5</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="6" id="RadioGroup1_8">
      License number 6<br>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="7" id="RadioGroup1_9">
      License number 7</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h1>Your category, arranged by skill.</h1>
<table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="7" id="Categorie_0">
Not skilled - 7<br>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="6" id="Categorie_1">
Less skilled - 6</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="5" id="Categorie_2">
Unskilled - 5</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="4" id="Categorie_3">
      Average - 4</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="3" id="Categorie_4">
Skilled - 3</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="2" id="Categorie_5">
Good - 2</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="Categorie" value="1" id="Categorie_6">
Genius - 1</label>
      <label for="email"><br>
    Your email adress:</label>      <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label for="textarea">Comments and extra information:</label>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
<table width="200">
  <tr> </tr>
</table>
  </form>
```

Here you go... And correct me if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Might be a bit much to ask but how can I best include this is current code?

Comment: I can include this JavaScript directly in PHP?

Comment: Thank you! That would be of great use!

Comment: @FlobakemuWiarmome Run the snippet.. and choose your values... you will get your expected outputs..

Comment: I am trying to get it to work now but as of yet without success. I will continue to try though but I can't find really how it works yet.

Comment: Look.. Javascript is a client side language.. which runs thoroughly on the browser of the client.. what we did here is that we simply made a json array named Category which possesses all the requirements of the pairs of NUMBER vs SKILL LEVEL. Now we fetched the input of the user that which CATEGORYNUMBER did he select from the given radio buttons and the SKILL LEVEL from the other set of radio buttons... Then we called a validation function to check whether the input given by user is valid for submission of form on serverside (which might be your php or other serverside script)..

Comment: If the requirements of skill and the category were satisfied, it would return true and hence allow the form submission. else It will return false and not allow the form to be submitted.

Comment: Now if you have a dynamic list of skill-Category number pairs, you can get that from database through $.ajax() request... and if the list is small enough.. then you can get it saved as i uploaded a static list of category...

Comment: So when you run the snippet, If you select 3 lisence number and 4 skill level, then and only then you are allowed to participate... I don't actually know if you want that With any lisence number, the minimum required skill level is something... We can validate it using the same script like that also.. So It would be great if you clarify your requirements properly.

Comment: @FlobakemuWiarmome Got the explanation?

Comment: The license number is basically the skill level of any given applicant. The skill level (as found on your license, something fictional but only way of measuring according to the exercise) cannot be lower as the group you want to participate in as this is bound to your skill level as well. The requirements are basically that you cannot participate in the group that is a lower skill level than your (again, fictional) license states. But the applicant can apply in a skill group higher than the license states.

Comment: Yes I do, I kinda miss the technical know how at this moment on how to implement this into the file...

Comment: @FlobakemuWiarmome Run the snippet now.. I guess this is what you need

Comment: Thanks, it does work now! Sorry for my late reply but my computer needed an upgrade...

Comment: Then could you please mark my answer as correct ? @FlobakemuWiarmome